# Apply path to statically served content

Tags: rest, nginx, static, create-react-app

I'm statically serving a PWA builded with Create-React-App through Nginx.

This is my Nginx location configuration:

```
location / {
    root /etc/my_app/latest;
    index index.html;
    add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
    expires off;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept' always;
    allow all;
  }
```

So :

- When querying `https://my_domain_name_app/` it logically find the `index.html` file in `/etc/my_app/latest/index.html`
- When querying `https://my_domain_name_app/assets/image.png` it logically find the `image.png` file in `/etc/my_app/latest/assets/image.png`

But when my PWA's URL is, for example, `https://my_domain_name_app/login`, Nginx will try to find a file `login` in `/etc/my_app/latest/` and throw a 404 error instead of accessing the `/login` page of my application

How can I tell Nginx to differenciate the page of my application from the files I serve ?

Comment: Try adding the line: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`

Comment: This is the answer, thank you very much, I've been struggling with this simple things for days ahah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Richard Smith is correct, I had to add `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`